# Incremented int is resetting at the end of the function

Tags: c++

This is the function in question. The variable in question is `count1`. Prior to `return count1;` the function appears to reset count1 to either 1 or 2. The result of the final `cout` line is n lines where n=number of tries including the correct answer. Each line outputs a number that is 1 higher than the line below until `count1` = either 1 or 2. I haven't been able to establish a pattern as to which it will finally output.

The questions themselves are simply placeholders.

What on Earth is going on?

Note: I am a very new programmer, and I am aware that there are likely more efficient ways to do what I am doing that I have not learned. I'm open to suggestions, but my understanding of those suggestions will likely be hampered by my unfamiliarity with C++

```
int q1(int count1)                      //q1() is always fed a value of 1.
{
    using namespace std;
    if (count1 <= 3)                    //User gets 3 tries to answer for full credit.
    {                                   //count1 is returned in order to determine user score.

        cout << "What is 2+2 \n";       //problem appears to occur between here and the end of this if statement.
        double a1;
        cin >> a1;

        if (a1 == 4)
        {
            cout << "Yup. You know what 2+2 is. \n\n";
        }
        else
        {
            wrong();                    //wrong() is a single line void function using std::cout and nothing else.
            q1(++count1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You have used all three tries. Next question. \n\n";
        ++count1;                       //count1 is incremented for an if statement in int main()
    }       
    cout << count1 << "\n";             //This line is strictly for debugging
    return count1;
}
```

Output of the final `cout` line looks along the lines of this:
5
4
3
2
Without `\n`
5432

EDIT:

There was an answer below that is deleted for some reason that appeared to resolve my problem.

The answer stated I should replace `q1(++count1)` with `count1 = q1(++count1);`

In my mind this shouldn't work, but in practice it seems to work. Why?

Comment: In a question, you can use backticks (` ) to format pieces of code inline, making your question more readable (for example, with `count1` in the 1st paragraph).

Comment: I may need a little more clarification. New to both programming and the stackoverflow. I'd love to make answering the question as easy as possible, but I'm not sure how exactly you mean for me to use them.

Comment: Sorry, putting one on each side of the word(s) that you want to be in code format will do so. ` Hello world ` (without the spaces) becomes `Hello world`

Comment: @Ike I'm not sure either. It actually seemed to work, and I was in the middle of asking for an edit for clarification, as I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around that. That being said, it's a basic question because I'm new to this, and even your explanation there is actually a bit above my knowledge.

Comment: Is this an exercise to learn recursion? It seems like a loop would be more straightforward here.

Comment: It's just an idea I had. I wanted to write a program to test a user with basic questions, and then write a program to interpret and answer those questions. Obviously the second one is more difficult, but right now this is just where I'm at. No exercise, just using the very limited knowledge I have to play with the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using recursion, the first time your function runs count1 is 1 (as you said). If the user answers right, then your function will return 1, because the value of count1 never changes.

If the user answers wrong, then count1 increases by 1 and gives it's value to a new function (of the same type). Keep in mind that you pass the value of count1, that means the new function (the second `q1()`) will get the number 2 but will have a new variable `count1`. They may have the same name, but they are different variables.

There are two ways to solve your problem:

Either by using pointers, this way you pass the address of count1, and each function changes the same variable. (This is the hardest way and not the most efficient) or

Instead of making recursive calls, you can make a `while` like so:

```
int q1(int count1)
{
    using namespace std;
    while (count1 <= 3) //Run as long as user has chances
    {
        cout << "What is 2+2 \n";
        double a1;
        cin >> a1;

        if (a1 == 4)
        {
            cout << "Yup. You know what 2+2 is. \n\n";

            //Using `break` you stop the running `while` so the next
            //step is for the function to return
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            wrong();

            //By incrementing `count1` the next time the `while` runs
            //if user ran out of tries it will not enter the loop, so
            //it will return `count1` which would most likely be 4
            count1++;
        }
    }

    //Here the function is about to return, so you check if user won or lost
    if (count1 == 4)
        cout << "You have used all three tries. Next question. \n\n"; 

    //Debug
    cout << count1 << "\n";

    //Return
    return count1;
}
```

Comment: Nice -- though there's also one slightly more immediate way (but using loops here is certainly easier). Simply capture the return value. `count1 = q1(count1 + 1);` Since the OP was already returning the resulting counter in each successive recursive call, that alone should suffice to capture the number of guesses being made to the outer callers without involving references or pointers. The code was already mostly right except it was just discarding the return values.

Comment: @Ike that is indeed a simpler way, however each function that runs consumes memory until it is finished, which means in this case ~4 functions may run at the same time until the last one is finished and each of them will finish one by one. For only 4 functions it's not a big deal, but in my opinion it's a terrible programming habbit for such a simple problem.

Comment: Yeah -- except I wouldn't call it simpler to use recursion for this type of thing outside of a functional language. I just thought of it in terms of how op was mostly correct with the recursive solution but just missing one little thing by forgetting to pay attention to the return value.